# Template members in class

Tags: c++, xcode, templates

I am trying to include template member in non-template class. Here's example:

.h

```
class ncScript {
public:
 template<typename T> void RegisterConstant( T value, const char *N );
};
```

.cpp

```
template<> 
void RegisterConstant<int>( int value, const char * N ) {
     // Do something.
}

template<>
void RegisterConstant<bool>( bool value, const char * N ) {
     // Do something.
}

// and so on
```

But when I am trying to use it like:

```
_luaCache["myluafile"].RegisterConstant( 13, "myvariable" );
```

I am getting the following error in Xcode ( LLVM compiler ):

```
Explicit specialization of 'RegisterConstant<int>' after instantiation.
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `ncScript::` in front of your specializations. Either that or post your *real* code. And why aren't you just *overloading* that member ?

Comment: [See it live](http://ideone.com/7p1Ovg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that the class is instantiated before the compiler sees the specializations.

For example if it sees this, the class is either already instantiated or will be here.

```
_luaCache["myluafile"].RegisterConstant( 13, "myvariable" );
```

if the specializations are implemented later you will get an error.

simplest solution is putting the specializations *declarations* in the header ie.

```
template<>  
void RegisterConstant<int>( int value, const char * N );
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working! I simply forgot to declare function outside of class.